# Updating negative values in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-preprocessing

I have the following dataframe:

| Partner | 0 Days | 1-30 Days | 31 - 60 Days | 61 - 90 Days | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 154678 | 200.00 | -50.00 | 160.00 | 300.00 | 610.00 |
| 234567 | 100.00 | -150.00 | 50.00 | 120.00 | 120.00 |

- step 1: look for the negative value in each row. For example 2nd row has -150.00
- step 2: take the maximum positive number available. For example 2nd rows has 120.00
- step 3: compare absolute value of the negative value(-150) with 120
- step 4: if absolute value is less than the max positive number simply convert the negative number to zero
  and subtract it from biggest positive number.
- step 5: else, like we have in 2nd row, convert biggest number to 0 and add the value of it to the negative number. we will have -30.00 in 2nd row. Then take the current biggest number which is 0 in our case and repeat the same process. keep doing this until the absolute value is less than than max positive number available.
- step 6: Once we reach this level repeat step 4

Resulted Dataframe should look like this:

| Partner | 0 Days | 1-30 Days | 31 - 60 Days | 61 - 90 Days | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 154678 | 200.00 | 0.0000 | 160.00 | 250.00 | 610.00 |
| 234567 | 70.00 | 0.0000 | 50.00 | 0.0000 | 120.00 |

I have tried so many different ways to iterate through rows but I couldn't solve it.

I tried to iterate through the columns of each row but all the methods I have tried didn't give me the results I expected. Even couldn't get close results.

Comment: is it certain that there will only ever be at most one negative value in a row? I see a recursive function or a while loop here

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudocode can be transformed into python code by using the `idxmin` and `ìdxmax` functions. Define

```
def equalize_row(row):
    idx_neg = row.idxmin()
    to_equalize = row.loc[idx_neg]
    while to_equalize < 0:
        idx=row.idxmax()
        to_equalize = to_equalize + row.loc[idx]
        if to_equalize < 0:
            row[idx] = 0
        else:
            row[idx] = to_equalize
    row[idx_neg] = 0
```

And then you can apply it to all rows by

```
temp = pd.DataFrame([[100,700,300,-900,200],[100,-700,300,900,600]],
                    index=[154678,234567],
                    columns=['0 Days','1-30 Days','31 - 60 Days','61 - 90 Days','Total'])

for i,r in temp.iloc[:,:-1].iterrows():
    equalize_row(r)
```